# How do to a php wildcard replace on a urlencoded field

Tags: php, replace, wildcard, urlencode

I have several encoded fields that look like this:

317+NALON++RD%2C%2BGananoque%2C%2BOntario%2C%2BCanada

The easy part is replacing the "+" with a space.

My challenge is replacing the "%2C" or "%2B" with a space.

Sometime the text after the "%" may be different, but it will always be two characters.

I tried using str_replace("%**", " ",urlencode($string)) but no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace()` doesn't deal with wildcards. You can use regular expressions for this instead (as long as you're sure that you want to change ALL %** to spaces):

```
preg_replace("/(%..|\+)+/", ' ', $string);
```

This will take your `$string` (which I presume to be already URL encoded) and replace all '+'s and '%**'s with spaces. <s>Note that it will replace the sequence '%2C%2B' with two spaces (for two matches)</s> EDIT: the regular expression now matches any number of space-substitutes and substitutes one space for all of them.